# Integrate asio::io_service into ACE_Reactor based app

Tags: c++, boost-asio, reactor, ace

I want to integrate module with boost::asio::io_service into application with ACE_Reactor and I do not want to use separate thread for this.
In asio::io_service I can call poll_one() method to execute  at most one handler that is ready to run.
The main question is: When it is better to call it?

Comment: What platform are you writing against?

Comment: @MikelF Linux  CentOS

Comment: @MikelF but why this is important? Both frameworks are cross-platform...

Comment: I have experience with both frameworks in the WIndows environment. Although they are cross-platform, there are differences in how ACE_Reactor can work.